# Does GetMessageTime overflow like GetTickCount

Tags: winapi

Does [GetMessageTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644939(v=vs.85).aspx) (and thus, the *time* member of the [KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644967(v=vs.85).aspx)) suffer from the same limitation of [GetTickCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408(v=vs.85).aspx) of reseting back to 0, once the value crosses *49.7* days?

Comment: This sort of question makes me sad. You linked to MSDN documentation which directly answers the question that you asked.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Indeed, I feel like an idiot for missing that part bleh sorry!

Comment: It never occurred to me, but something about the documentation and function signatures doesn't look right. `GetMessageTime` returns a `LONG` (i.e. a `signed int`), but `GetTickCount` as well as the `KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT`'s *time* member use `DWORD`s (i.e. `unsigned int`). I had always assumed, that the message timestamps were set to the result of `GetTickCount`, but given the above, that cannot be. Does anyone have details on how those API calls relate, if at all?

Comment: @IInspectable Yes, the docs make clear that they are (and after all, 32 bits is 32 bits, right?), but the return value is declared as a `LONG` for some reason, just to make us all scratch our heads and have to cast it.  Go figure.

Comment: @PaulSanders: I don't see anything in the documentation, that makes *anything* clear. After all, -1 and 4294967295 are different values, even though they share the same representation (assuming 2s complement). Besides, a 32 bit pointer is also 32 bits. A UTF-32 code unit is also 32 bits. Unsure what you are trying to say.

Comment: @IInspectable The docs for both fuctions say that they return the time in milliseconds since the system was started.  To get from `GetMessageTime` what you would have gotten from `GetTickCount`, just cast the result to a `DWORD`.

Comment: @PaulSanders: The documentation also explains, when those API calls wrap around, and to which value they wrap. Both are different. Anyway, I was asking for details on those API calls, and why they return different values.

Comment: @IInspectable Documentation bug, see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140122-00/?p=2013.

Comment: @Tirafesi +1from me for being willing to be so open about your mistakes in public (and for having the courage to leave the question on the site). You will go far.

Comment: The `GetMessageTime()` function casts its return value to `LONG`.

Comment: @PaulSanders: That link explains a lot, but doesn't have any indication of a documentation bug. The documentation is accurate. Apparently, there used to be a bug in the documentation (if you follow the comments on the blog entry), that has since been fixed. It's still unclear to me, why the API decided to return different types for what is essentially the same thing.

Comment: @IInspectable Well, Raymond makes it clear how the function actually behaves, and that is at odds with the documentation.  I don't know about you, but I'm inclined to believe Raymond.  Anyway, think about it, how would _you_ implement it?  I know what I would do: `return (LONG) GetTickCount ();` and to hell with it.  And why the weird return type?  God knows, maybe an intern designed it.

Comment: @PaulSanders: I still don't understand, where you believe to see an inconsistency between the blog entry and the documentation. The blog entry never challenges the documentation. All there is is an apology (*"Sorry about the inconsistency in signed/unsigned-ness."*). But that doesn't invalidate the documentation, the documentation *is* accurate.

Comment: @IInspectable Ah, you're right as usual.  I thought the description in the documentation of what happens when the return value wraps was incorrect, but when I read it more carefully I can see that actually it's fine.  Sorry, tired, didn't sleep well.  Time to kick back and relax, before you mention UI Automation :)

Comment: Easy to test, write a program that prints out both `GetTickCount()` and `static_cast<DWORD>(GetMessageTime())` and run it for more than 25 days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both [GetMesssageTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644939.aspx) as well as [GetTickCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408.aspx) wrap around to the smallest value after reaching the largest value that can be represented by the respective return value type. There is an inconsistency in return types, where `GetMessageTime` returns a `LONG` (`signed int`), and `GetTickCount` returns a `DWORD` (`unsigned int`).

The documentation for `GetMessageTime` calls out:

> The return value from the GetMessageTime function does not necessarily increase between subsequent messages, because the value [...] **wraps to the minimum value for a long integer if the timer count exceeds the maximum value for a long integer**.

The documentation for `GetTickCount` describes a different wrapping mode, due to the signedness of the return value:

> The elapsed time is stored as a `DWORD` value. Therefore, the time will **wrap around to zero if the system is run continuously for 49.7 days**.

So both return values wrap to different values at different points in time. `GetMessageTime` wraps to -2147483648 after it reaches ‭2147483647‬ (roughly after 24.9 days), whereas `GetTickCount` wraps to 0 when exceeding ‭4294967295‬. After the initial wrap-around, both return values wrap around at the same frequency, where the points in time are shifted by half the time period of one cycle.

That's as far as the guarantees for the C language go. Since this is Windows, we can restrict ourselves to the stronger guarantees of the Win32 ABI, that requires twos-complement arithmetic. Given that, the binary representation of the return values of `GetMessageTime` and `GetTickCount` are identical. If you decide to cast the return value of `GetMessageTime` to `DWORD`, you'll observe identical wrapping of the value as you would from `GetTickCount`.

It is not entirely clear to me, why `GetMessageTime` returns a signed value. It may have been chosen to make it easier to perform what was believed to be the more common calculation. That's speculation, though. Raymond Chen's blog entry [What clock do MSG.time and GetMessageTime use?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140122-00/?p=2013) has more information, but doesn't answer the question *"why?"*.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the explanation! I had also noticed the mismatch between the return types, but I just assumed that it was a mistake in the documentation, where the return type for GetMessageType should have been ULONG, so someone forgot to add that *U* heh

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the remarks section even says so.

Comment: Sigh... I don't even know how I missed that. Thanks!

Comment: That cannot be the correct answer. `signed int` and `unsigned int` have different ranges. If the documentation is correct, then `GetMessageTime` and `GetTickCount` wrap around at different time points, to different values.

Comment: @IInspectable I'm afraid it is, see my comment above, although you have sharp eyes, I'll give you that. _If the docmentation is correct_ Yeah, well, no comment. After all, we know that MS _never_ slip up in that department (!)